# How to create User Interface for Quiz module in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, user-interface, ios7

I am very newly to iPhone. I am working on Quiz kind of app using XIB for iPhone only. My problem is i need to create an User interface design for n number of quiz question as i have attached below. Can anyone please suggest me what should be the best way to create this? I am getting All questions and their options from our backend server. I am getting unique id as test_id for every quiz question as i have mentioned in my JSON model.  It's possible by using table view section(for question text) and four rows (for options) for each section, but now the problem is if user will select option B for test id 1, and option A for test id 10 as answer, then how can i get the selected user answer option B and option A before tap on submit button. please give me suggestion for the same.

here is my JSON model for Quiz module:

```
{
    "test_details": [
        {
            "test_id": 1,
            "test_qus": "which of the following allows the HP ENVY Beats All-in-One PC to swiftly switch between applications?",
            "test_ans_optionA": "Quad-Core 1.0 GHz processor",
            "test_ans_optionB": "Windows® 8.1 OS",
            "test_ans_optionC": "Intel® Haswell Core Processor",
            "test_ans_optionD": "Windows 7 OS",
            "test_correct_ans": "optionA"
        },
        {
            "test_id": 2,
            "test_qus": "which of the following makes HP ENVY Beats All-in-One PC the best PC for Beats All-in-One PC the best PC for",
            "test_ans_optionA": "SRS Premium sound",
            "test_ans_optionB": "Monster Beats Solo headphones",
            "test_ans_optionC": "Beats AudioTM quad speakers and quad",
            "test_ans_optionD": "Windows 7 OS",
            "test_correct_ans": "optionB"
        }
]
}
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a tableview and take section for questions and for every section take 4 row for answer. i think its working better

Comment: Thanks@SRNayak.. I am trying the same but the problem is how can i get the user's selected answer for all table rows at last? pls help me

Comment: Can you also show how you fill the table with this model? However I would make "answers" property as array of objects and correct answer would indicate the index of the "answers" array. Then each item in answers could be in form: `{"selected":0,"title":"SRS Premium sound"}` in your example `test_id` will be the radiogroup id

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'GrelaActually i have saved this full JSON data in my NSObject based custom class. And i have an array of custom objects. So, for filling the table view i can get values from my mutable array index wise. Each answer options should have one radio button. Once user will select any options button bg image will change to selected one. I need to display one submit button as table footer view. Once user will tap on submit button then i need to calculate his quiz score by comparing there answer with correct answer. At the time, user can select only one option for each question.

Answer (score 0):

To have it dynamic you need to prepare in storyboard table with "dynamic prototypes" as content and prepare X of the prototype cells where X is the number of different cells (table rows) you may need (e.g. from screenshot I see 2, 1. Question cell, 2. Radiobutton cell)

Then implement UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource

You will have additional problem with radiobuttons as you need to maintain multiple selections (for each radiogroup single selection).

```
//will hold source of the table (data model) that will be maintained
NSMutableArray *dataSource;//of NSMutableDictionary objects
```

To update selection use following

```
#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate
-(void)            textView:(UITableView *)tableView
    didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSMutableDictionary * cellData = dataSource[indexPath.row];
    if(cellData) {
        //here maintain selection state and reload table data e.g. cellData can store "selected" property
    } else {
        //error no data for cell at this index
    }
}
```

source of the table

```
#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [dataSource count];
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSMutableDictionary *cellData = dataSource[indexPath.row];
    NSString *cellId = nil;
    NSInteger type = [[cellData valueForKey:@"type"] integerValue];//datasource can store type that will indicate which cell to display (integer is used so switch can be used)
    switch (type) {
        case 0:
            //header cell
            cellId = @"headerCell";//this is the cell identifier set in storyboard
        break;
        case 1:
        default:
            //radiobutton row - default
            cellId = @"radioButtonCell";
        break;
    }
    MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId
                                                         forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setData:cellData];//MyCustomCell implements the setData method

    return cell;
}
```

and basically that's it

Comment: Thanks@Lukasz, Sry for late response i am working with XIB. How can i get the user selected options question wise with XIB?

Comment: Can you update your question with more details e.g. how do you fill it with data etc. In my implementation the dataSource dictionary per row contains the group id, that's why I can maintain single selection per radiogroup (traversing through datasource and comparing this radiogroup id to only modify "selected" state on those items).

Comment: @LukaszPlease check my updated question. Kindly let me know in case of any clarification for my problem.